# Typing arbitrary properties passed in constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a pattern I'm tyring to migrate to typescript where we pass an object containing metadata properties to the main class those properties are compromised of a common class but can have extended functionality.

I want to be able to 1) type the `metadata` object on the class and 2) generate typed getter/setters for each of those properties that uses the `value` interface from the main property base class

Here is a contrived example

```js
// Javascript
class Image {
    constructor(metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;

        Object.keys(this.metadata).forEach((property) => {
            Object.defineProperty(this, property, {
                get: function() {
                    return this.metadata[property].value;
                },
                set: function(new_value) {
                    this.metadata[property].value = new_value;
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how I typed the Property classes

```
class ImageProperty<T> {
    protected _value: T;
    protected _defaultValue: T;

    constructor(defaultValue: T) {
        this._value = defaultValue;
        this._defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    reset() {
        this._value = this._defaultValue;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    set value(newValue: T) {
        this._value = newValue;
    }
}

class WrappedProperty extends ImageProperty<Number> {
    constructor(defaultValue: number, public min: number, public max: number) {
        super(defaultValue);
    }

    set value(newValue: number) {
        const old = this._value;

        while (newValue < this.min) {
            newValue += this.max + 1 - this.min;
        }

        this._value = ((newValue - this.min) % (this.max + 1 - this.min)) + this.min;

    }
}

class OrientationProperty extends ImageProperty<mat3> {
    transform(transform: mat3) {
        this.value = mat3.multiply([], this.value, transform);
    }

    reset() {
        this._value = this._defaultValue ?? mat3.identity();
    }
}
```

The problem is that both the `metadata` proptery and the getter/setters are untyped

e.g.,

```
const image = new Image({
    orientation: new OrientationProperty(mat3.create()),
    timepoint: new WrappedProperty(0, 0, 20),
    height: new ImageProperty(256),
    width: new ImageProperty(256),
    name: new ImageProperty('my-image'),
});
image.metadata.orientation.transform('foo'); // Allowed becuase generic type on properties is unknown
image.width = 500; // width not detected
```

Is there a less verbose way of setting these types than duplicating the `metadata` object with an interface and manually adding getters/setters for each property in `metadata` object?

```
export interface ImageMetadata {
    orientation: OrientationProperty;
    timepoint: WrappedProperty;
    height: ImageProperty<number>;
    width: ImageProperty<number>;
    name: ImageProperty<string>;
}
class Image {
    metadata: ImageMetadata;

    constructor(metadata: ImageMetadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    get orientation() {
        return this.metadata.orientation.value;
    }
    set orientation(orientation) {
        this.metadata.orientation.value = orientation;
    }

    get timepoint() {
        return this.metadata.timepoint.value;
    }
    set timepoint(timepoint) {
        this.metadata.timepoint.value = timepoint;
    }

    get height() {
        return this.metadata.height.value;
    }
    set height(height) {
        this.metadata.height.value = height;
    }

    get width() {
        return this.metadata.width.value;
    }
    set width(width) {
        this.metadata.width.value = width;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.metadata.name.value;
    }
    set name(name) {
        this.metadata.name.value = name;
    }
}
```

Note in my codebase there are a handful of variants and up to 50 different properties for each so this becomes very verbose. I did my best to minimize the use case but assume that majorly refactoring this pattern is not within scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a factory method that returns a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) as follows:

```
type Unwrapped<P> = P extends ImageProperty<infer T> ? T : never; 

const createImage = (metadata: ImageMetadata) => new Proxy(new Image(metadata), {
  get: (target, key: keyof ImageMetadata) => target.metadata[key].value,
  set: (target, key: keyof ImageMetadata, value) =>
           target.metadata[key].value = value,
  has: (target, key) => key in target.metadata
}) as Image & { [K in keyof ImageMetadata]: Unwrapped<ImageMetadata[K]> };
```

The type of the proxy will be an intersection type containing all the properties of the original `Image` class and all the "unwrapped" properties of the `ImageMetadata` class.

Here's a complete example. I simplified your code a little for readability, but the same principle applies.

```
class ImageProperty<T> {
    protected _value: T;
    protected _defaultValue: T;

    constructor(defaultValue: T) {
        this._value = defaultValue;
        this._defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    
    set value(newValue: T) {
        this._value = newValue;
    }
}

interface ImageMetadata {
    name: ImageProperty<string>;
    height: ImageProperty<number>;
    width: ImageProperty<number>;
}

class Image {
    metadata: ImageMetadata;

    constructor(metadata: ImageMetadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }
}

type Unwrapped<P> = P extends ImageProperty<infer T> ? T : never; 

const createImage = (metadata: ImageMetadata) => new Proxy(new Image(metadata), {
  get: (target, key: keyof ImageMetadata) => target.metadata[key].value,
  set: (target, key: keyof ImageMetadata, value) =>
           target.metadata[key].value = value,
  has: (target, key) => key in target.metadata
}) as Image & { [K in keyof ImageMetadata]: Unwrapped<ImageMetadata[K]> };  

const image = createImage({
  name: new ImageProperty('original'),
  width: new ImageProperty(0),
  height: new ImageProperty(0)
});

console.log(image.name); // original
console.log(image.width); // 0
console.log(image.height); // 0

image.name = 'updated';
image.width = 100;
image.height = 200;

console.log(image.name); // updated
console.log(image.width); // 100
console.log(image.height); // 200
```

To make sure that no `Image` object is created without wrapping it into a proxy, you could include the factory method as a `static` method in the `Image` class, and make the constructor private.

Answer (score 0):

I think an option lies [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21326#issuecomment-487778597) - a working recommendation is to  re-assign the class itself to a variable that can act like a class but has the modified type - which can be anything you want:

```
class _SomeClassWithMetadata<T> {
    constructor(metadata: T) {
        Object.keys(metadata).forEach(k => {
            Object.defineProperty(this, k, {
                // define getter
                get: () => { /* */ }
            })
        })
    }
}

const SomeClassWithMetadata: new<T>(a: T) => _SomeClassWithMetadata<T> & T = _SomeClassWithMetadata as any;

new SomeClassWithMetadata({ a: 1 }).a // accessing the getter
```